# Linear regression: not noramalising by y's norm

Tags: machine-learning

I was recently reading an [article on Pearson correlation, and OLS coefficients](https://brenocon.com/blog/2012/03/cosine-similarity-pearson-correlation-and-ols-coefficients/). I came across the following section.

> Finally, these are all related to the coefficient in a one-variable
>   linear regression. For the OLS model yi≈axi with Gaussian noise, whose
>   MLE is the least-squares problem  \begin{align}\arg\min_a \sum (y_i –
>  ax_i)^2\end{align} a few lines of calculus shows a is
>
> \begin{align}  OLSCoef(x,y) &= \frac{ \sum x_i y_i }{ \sum x_i^2 } 
>  = \frac{ \langle x, y \rangle}{ ||x||^2 }  \end{align}
>
> This looks like another normalized inner product. But unlike cosine
>   similarity, we aren’t normalizing by y’s norm — instead we only use
>   x’s norm (and use it twice): denominator of ||x|| ||y|| versus ||x||2.
>
> Not normalizing for y is what you want for the linear regression: if y
>   was stretched to span a larger range, you would need to increase a to
>   match, to get your predictions spread out too.

I understand that using calculus we can arrive at an expression for finding `a`, the coefficient. The expression's denominator turns out to not contain y's norm. In the last paragraph of the excerpt, I could not understand the following line

> Not normalizing for y is what you want for the linear regression

Why don't we want to normalize for y? What is the physical/geometrical significance of this?

Comment: Thanks! I will use LaTeX. Also, I do have provided a link to the source.